# Looking for the name of a post apocalyptic/sci-fi tv show or film

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

Every once in a while this starts nagging me, I have really no idea and not much to go on so here goes...

A man wearing a blue? uniform walks into a town that looks abandoned and empty and all covered in dust.  The skies are brown/dirty with no sun.  He goes into the upstairs of one of the houses. He stops at I think a fireplace, examines something, or it’s like he’s remembering something.  Then downstairs in the street, a man/person wearing rags/robes with bandages covering his face starts banging on a fire hydrant with a stick/pipe. More people in bandages/robes start appearing, there's a chase in the town. I don't remember much but he's chased into wastes? through a gully or ditch and then a vehicle (only really remember that it was steel in colour) shows up and a woman comes and shoots one or two of the people chasing him.

That’s about all I remember. I was about 6 or 7 maybe and it was afternoon maybe a little later.  I thought maybe **Star Trek**, but after searching I don't think it is. I think it might be 80's, maybe early 90's. I think it's sci-fi rather than post-apocalyptic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a scene from Buck Rogers in the 25th Century that pretty closely matches your description.  However his suit is white (which in the dark looks blue) and he is with a robot on his explorations and chase)

The Men in rags/bandages do come out and start banging on metal pipes and fire hydrants and chasing him. (31'19")

The "fireplace" he examines was actually a gravestone with his parents name on it.  (33'52")

He is rescued by a woman in a Armored Personnel carrier (which fires lasers at the bad guys chasing them away) (37'35")

Starts exploring the dead city: (30'57")

Comment: yeah this was it quite different from how i remember though...thank you

Comment: Your link to the Youtube video has gone dead. Any chance you could find it (or another one) again to re-link?

Comment: I checked, could not find a replacement video on YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

"The Omega Man" (1971)?

It does have the look of a Star Trek episode and stars Charlton Heston as a man who thinks he's the last surviving human in a world suffering the after effects of biological warfare. He wears a blue uniform in this movie which is the 2nd movie adaptation of Richard Matheson's 1954 novel "I Am Legend". I seem to remember the scene you're describing but can't find it. The trailer from YouTube is posted below. You can see shots of Charlton Heston in a blue uniform and the robed figures you might be remembering.

Answer (score 1):

"The Andromeda Strain"?

The opening scene is someone in a decom suit walking through a town where everyone is dead, except for a baby and a drunk.